# How to implement scrolling of the tableView to the top hiding the search bar in its tableheaderView?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have already gone through some similar questions and tried implementing their solutions. However they seem to have some problem in especially iPhone X. I am using deployment target as 9.3.

To do so, I wrote this code but iPhone X puts tableView higher hiding more than half of the first row along with the search bar too.

```
 override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
               self.tableView.contentOffset = CGPoint(x: 0.0,y: 0.0)

        }
```

also the below snippet appears to have no effect at all:

```
self.tableView.scrollToRow(at: IndexPath( row: 0, section: 0), at: UITableViewScrollPosition.top, animated: false)
```

Adding full code if you want to have a look at it.

```
import UIKit

class CountryTableViewController: UITableViewController, UISearchResultsUpdating {

    let countriesArray = ["Afghanistan", "Albania", "Algeria", "Afghanistan", "Albania", "Algeria", "Afghanistan", "Albania", "Algeria", "Afghanistan", "Albania", "Algeria", "Afghanistan", "Albania", "Algeria", "Afghanistan", "Albania", "Algeria", "Afghanistan", "Albania", "Algeria"]
    let  countrycodes = ["+93", "+355", "+213", "+93", "+355", "+213", "+93", "+355", "+213", "+93", "+355", "+213", "+93", "+355", "+213", "+93", "+355", "+213", "+93", "+355", "+213"]
    var filteredArray = [String]()
    var searchController = UISearchController()
    var resultsController = UITableViewController()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.


        let cancelButton: UIBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Cancel", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(cancel))
        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = cancelButton

        let searchButton: UIBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(searchButtonAction))
        searchButton.image = UIImage(named: "search")
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = searchButton

        searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: resultsController)
        tableView.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar

        searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self

        resultsController.tableView.delegate = self
        resultsController.tableView.dataSource = self

       automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false

    }

    func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController)
    {
        filteredArray = countriesArray.filter({ (countriesArray:String) -> Bool in
            if countriesArray.contains(searchController.searchBar.text!)
            {
                return true
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }

        })
        resultsController.tableView.reloadData()
        automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false
    }

    @objc func cancel() {
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

    }
    @objc func searchButtonAction() {
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        self.searchController.isActive = true
        self.searchController.searchBar.text = ""
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if tableView == resultsController.tableView
        {
            return filteredArray.count
        }
        else
        {
            return countriesArray.count
        }

    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {
        let cell = UITableViewCell()

        if tableView == resultsController.tableView
        {
            cell.textLabel?.text = filteredArray[indexPath.row]
            cell.detailTextLabel?.text = countrycodes[indexPath.row]
            cell.imageView?.image = UIImage (named: "Flag0")
        }
        else
        {
            cell.textLabel?.text = countriesArray[indexPath.row]
            cell.detailTextLabel?.text = countrycodes[indexPath.row]
            cell.imageView?.image = UIImage (named: "Flag0")
        }


        return cell

    }
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        print(indexPath.row, indexPath.section)


    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

        self.tableView.scrollToRow(at: IndexPath( row: 0, section: 0), at: UITableViewScrollPosition.bottom, animated: false)
          // self.tableView.contentOffset = CGPoint(x: 0.0,y: 0.0)
          //  self.tableView.setContentOffset(.zero, animated: true)
        //self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(-64, 0, 0, 0)
        self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false;

    }
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

     //  self.tableView.scrollToRow(at: IndexPath( row: 0, section: 0), at: UITableViewScrollPosition.top, animated: false)
       //   self.tableView.contentOffset = CGPoint(x: 0.0,y: 44.0)
      //  self.tableView.setContentOffset(.zero, animated: true)

    }




}
```

Comment: Do you add the search bar in the storyboard or programmatically?

Comment: I implemented programmatically.

Comment: Can you add the significant code?

Comment: Added @Kerberos.

Answer (score 0):

you should add `definesPresentationContext = true` in your viewDidLoad().